# Efficiently splitting a population into an arbitrary number of parts randomly

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

First of all: I wasn't sure where to post this, but since it involves probability distributions I decided to go with Mathematics stack exchange.

Notation used in this question: $x$~$U(a,b)$ means $x$ is a random number chosen from a uniform distribution on the interval $[a,b]$, whereas $x$~$N(\lambda,\sigma^2)$ means that $x$ is a random number chosen from a normal distribution with mean $\lambda$ and variance $\sigma$.

I'm working on a (cellular automata) particle diffusion model on a triangular grid.

Each site on the grid has a certain number of particles on it.

Each site on the grid has up to six neighbors.

At each iteration the particles may spread to a different (neighboring site) according to a probability.

A naive approach would be this:

0. Chose a probablity $p$, with which particles stay at rest.
1. Create as many random numbers ~$U(0,1)$ as there are particles at the current site.
2. For each of the random numbers

   if the random number is smaller than $p$ do nothing

   if the random number is larger than $p$, it is in the interval $[p, 1]$. You can split this interval into however many parts you need (where the number of subintervals is equal to the number of neighbors) and depending on the subinterval, move the particle to that location.

The problem with this approach is, that is very computationally intesive, when you have a large number of particles.

**My current approach, that seems to be flawed:**

When the number of particles is very large, I expect the distribution to be well approximated by a gaussian distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$. The following pseudocode is loosely following a description in chapter 5.7 of "Cellular Automata Modeling of Physical Systems" by Bastien Chopard and Michal Droz, but I have to modify it for "arbitrary" numbers of neighbors (1 to 6 neighbors):

0. Let $n$ be the number of particles at a given site and $p$ the probability to stay at rest.
1. Generate a random number $n_s$ ~$N(np, np(1-p))$ .This is the number of particles that will stay at rest. $n_m = n - n_s$ is the number of particles that will move.
2. Distribute the $n_m$ particles to the neighboring sites.

   2.1 If the number of neighbors is even, lets say $2k$, generate a random number ~$N(n_m \cdot \frac{1}{2}, n_m\cdot \frac{1}{4})$. This splits the particles into two groups. One group will get distributed to $k$ neighbors and the other group will get distributed to the other $k$ neighbors. Continue splitting the population like this until the remaining groups of neighbors are either odd, or just a single neighbor, in which case you can distribute the particles to that neighbor.

   2.2 If the number of neighbors is odd, lets say $(2k-1)$,  generate a random number ~$N(n_m \cdot \frac{1}{2k-1}, n_m\cdot \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2})$. This splits the particles into two groups. One group will get distributed to a single neighbor, the remaining will be distributed onto $2k-2$ neighbors. Since this is an even number, we can follow the procedure for an even number of neighbors.

---

Example:
We want to distribute $1000$ particles onto $6$ neighbors with a probability of $80$% for each particle to stay at rest.

0. Let $p = 0.8$ and $n = 1000$
1. Generate $n_s$ ~$N(np, np(1-p))$. Let's say $n_s = 700$. This means $n_m = 300$
2. The number $6$ is even, so we split $n_m$ into two parts, each to be distributed onto $3$ neighbors. We do this by generating a number $n_{m_1}$~$N(n_m \cdot \frac{1}{2}, n_m\cdot \frac{1}{4})$ which will be the number to be distributed onto the first $3$ neighbors and a second number $n_{m_2} = n_m - n_{m_1}$, which will get distributed onto the second $3$ neighbors.
3. The number $3$ is odd, so we split $n_{m_1}$ into two parts. One to be distributed to one neighbor, one to be distributed to two neighbors. We do this by generating a number $n_{m_{1,1}}$~$N(n_{m_1} \cdot \frac{1}{3}, n_{m_1}\cdot \frac{1}{3^2})$, which is the number to be distributed to the single neighbor. Therefore the remaining $n_{m_{1,2}} = n_{m_1} - n_{m_{1,1}}$ are to be distributed to two neighbors.
4. The number $2$ is even, so we split $n_{m_{1,2}}$ into two parts. We generate a number $n_{m_{1,3}}$~$N(n_{m_{1,2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}, n_{m_{1,2}}\cdot \frac{1}{4})$ and $n_{m_{1,4}} = n_{m_{1,2}} - n_{m_{1,3}}$
5. $n_{m_{1,1}}$, $n_{m_{1,3}}$ and $n_{m_{1,4}}$ are the numbers of particles to be distributed to three neighbors from step 2.
6. Split $n_{m_2}$ following steps 3, 4 and 5. The resulting numbers will be the number of particles to be distributed to the second three neighbors from step 2.

---

**I am very certain my approach is valid for an even number of neighbors, but very unsure about the means and variances** to generate my numbers with - especially for odd number of neighbors. The numbers $n_m \cdot \frac{1}{2k-1}$ and $n_m\cdot \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$ are nothing more than a guess.

**Any help with explaining a flaw in my approach, or a different approach would be very much appreciated**